# Large text substitutions in Tcl

Tags: tcl

Within my Tcl script I'm building source code in another language. Let it be [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) source for example. I have Tcl code like this:

```
# `script' variable contains gnuplot source code
set script {
  set terminal pdf
  set output "chart.pdf"
  set title "[makeTitle]"
  plot "$dataFile" using 1:2 title ""
}

# Then I write `script' to file for later execution
```

Notice that `script` variable contains command call (`makeTitle`) and variable substitution (`dataFile`). The source code itself contains new lines, double quotes.

**Question:** how can I simply "evaluate" this variable to substitute command calls by their results and variables by their values? Expected result should look like this:

```
  set terminal pdf
  set output "chart.pdf"
  set title "R(S) Dependence"
  plot "r_s.txt" using 1:2 title ""
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the [subst](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/subst.htm) command:

```
set result [subst $script]
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach I commonly use in this type of situation is using `[string map]` with special symbols. For example:

```
set script {
    set terminal pdf
    set output "chart.pdf"
    set title "%MAKETITLE%"
    plot "%DATAFILE%" using 1:2 title ""
}
set script [string map [list %MAKETITLE% [makeTitle] %DATAFILE% $datafile] $script]
```

While glenn's answer of using `[subst]` is a good one and will work for the sample code you tested, it can run into issues as the original string gets more complex. Specifically, if it winds up containing characters that Tcl would interpret as commands to run or variables to substitute, you wind up needing to escape them, etc. By using `string map` and very specific character sequences to replace, you can limit the things that are changed to exactly what you need.